# How to get the kernel estimate given grid of densities

Tags: r, probability

Let *x* be a vector of values and *y* be a vector that is the density of x. Together they are a grid of densities.

Other than sampling from the grid and then feeding the sample to density(), I feel like that is too slow. Is there something like density() that takes in my grid values and grid density and makes a smoothed out kernel function? The point is I want to be able to use that as a function to make estimates between grid points, using approxfun sometimes gives negative values.

Comment: Since y is the density, can you just order x and y based on x, then generate a cumulative sums of y. Then the resulting curve can be used to get the area between two points? e.g., yCum(x2) - yCym(x1) will be the density between the two?

Comment: Why not make a weighted spline function with knots at boundaries.

Comment: A general approach is to treat the specified density y as a weight for the data x, then apply whatever model you want to x, such as density mixture estimation or whatever. That said, the results will probably be not too different from just interpolating between values. Linear interpolation will probably be enough, but if you want something more complicated you can take a look at monotone splines. A web search for that term should find some resources.